# Types of these phrases

Tags: adverbial-phrases

1. > She told Thu Zar **about the accident**.
2. > The bees stung the workman **to the death**.
3. > The Tun Foundation presented our school **with a generous
   >   donation**.
4. > Microscopic insects can only be seen **through a microscope**.
5. > You must not hammer nails into the wall **without permission**.
6. > The teacher showed the girls how to **cook the chicken curry**.

What are the types of the phrases in bold?

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  These are various kinds of construction, serving different syntactic functions, and it won't help anybody else to put them all in one place. Why don't you pick just one, and tell us what about it puzzles you?

Answer (score 1):

The first five are *prepositional phrases*. You can identify them by the fact that they each begin with a preposition:  **about, to, with, through, without**. I would say that all of these examples function to modify the verb; they fill an adverbial role.

(Incidentally, number two should be "stung...**to death**", not "stung...**to the death**".)

The bold part of number six is not a phrase at all.  It is a *part* of the *noun phrase* **how to cook the chicken curry** (which, as a whole, acts as the direct object of "showed".)  Notice that the "to" in this example is **not** a preposition—it is part of the infinitive **to cook**.

Comment: I think 1, 3, and 6 are Complements of the verb, not adverbials (if you take them away the sentences are ungrammatical). Isn't *cook the chicken curry* a verb phrase? [I know it's not a preposition phrase, of course!]

Comment: "How to cook chicken curry" is a piece of knowledge. That thing is what she showed . She showed (X) to the girls, or she showed the girls (X).  Either way, "the girls" is the indirect object, and (X) is the direct object, no matter whether (X) has a verb in it.

Comment: *To the death* is only used with *fight* as far as I know, as in *fight to the death*.